# How do I make an object follow path's animation

Tags: javascript, raphael

I've set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HighKickX/ap34g/) to illustrate my question.

I would like the red circles to stay on the path during the animation. Is there an "easy" way of doing this?

```
var r = Raphael(0, 0, "100%", "100%");

(function () {
    var el = r.path("M0 100L200 100").attr({fill: "none"}),
        elattrs = [{path: "M0 100L200 100"}, {path: "M0 100S100 150 200 100"}],
        now = 1;
    var set = r.set();
    set.push(
        el,
        r.circle(100, 100, 5).attr({fill: 'red'}),
        r.circle(50, 100, 5).attr({fill: 'red'}),
        r.circle(150, 100, 5).attr({fill: 'red'})
    );

    r.circle(40, 40, 20).attr({fill: 'blue'}).click(function () {
        el.stop().animate(elattrs[+(now = !now)], 1000, 'elastic');
    });
})();
```

​

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice method [Element.getPointAtLength](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getPointAtLength) which can be used for this purpose.

I've [forked and updated your code](http://jsfiddle.net/andersand/yxFdn/) to let the circle elements follow the animated path as you wanted. Stackoverflow forced me to paste the code here so here it is:

```
var r = Raphael(0, 0, "100%", "100%");

(function () {
    var paths = ["M0 100 L200 100",
                 "M0 100 S100 150 200 100"];
    var line = r.path(paths[0]).attr({fill: "none"}),
        elattrs = [{path: paths[0]}, {path: paths[1]}],
        now = 1;
    var guide = r.path(paths[1]).attr({stroke : "none"});
    var c1 = r.circle(50, 100, 5).attr({fill: 'red'}),
        c2 = r.circle(100, 100, 5).attr({fill: 'red'}),
        c3 = r.circle(150, 100, 5).attr({fill: 'red'});

    r.circle(40, 40, 20).attr({fill: 'blue'}).click(function () {
        now = now ? 0 : 1;
        line.stop().animate(elattrs[now], 1000, 'elastic');
        c1.stop().animate({cy : (now ? guide.getPointAtLength(50).y  : 100)}, 1000, 'elastic');
        c2.stop().animate({cy : (now ? guide.getPointAtLength(100).y : 100)}, 1000, 'elastic');
        c3.stop().animate({cy : (now ? guide.getPointAtLength(150).y : 100)}, 1000, 'elastic');
    });
})();
```

### ​

PS. See more examples [over here](http://benknowscode.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/finding-points-along-an-svg-path-using-raphael/).

Comment: Thank you for bringing me that method to my attention. It might be a good start for a solution. However, if you increase the bending of the line and lower animation speed, you will see that the circles doesn't stay on the path during the animation.

Comment: Here's something that will adapt to varying length, however not sure it fits your specification. Here the dots follow the same distribution, but maybe you want them to drop straight down instead. http://jsfiddle.net/andersand/yxFdn/8/

Comment: I was modifying your fork and came to the same result with slightly different code. Keeping the distribution is what I want, so no straight down effect. Starting and ending position of the circles are good now but they still leave the line during the animation.